# How to get datagrid to ignore unwanted columns

Tags: c#

I am using VS Express 2012 and SQL.

I have created a datagrid and used the designer to add the columns I want to display. This works fine. The column data gets entered into the correct column.

The problem is that the datagrid then goes and ads the raw SQL column names and dumps the data there as well.

How can I use datagrid.DataSource(dataTable) in a way that it only uses the columns I assigned in the designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're developing for WinForms...

Before assigning the DataSource, try setting:

```
datagrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.autogeneratecolumns%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> Columns are automatically generated when this property is set to true and the DataSource or DataMember properties are set or changed.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `AutoGenerateColumns` to false in the datagrid definition:

```
AutoGenerateColumns="false"
```